# Optimization with Python (scipy.optimize)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to maximize the following function using Python's scipy.optimize. However, after lots of trying, it doesn't seem to work. The function and my code are pasted below. Thanks for helping!

**Problem**

```
Maximize [sum (x_i / y_i)**gamma]**(1/gamma)
subject to the constraint sum x_i = 1; x_i is in the interval (0,1).
```

`x` is a vector of choice variables; `y` is a vector of parameters; `gamma` is a parameter. The `x`s must sum to one. And each `x` must be in the interval (0,1).

**Code**

```
def objective_function(x, y):
    sum_contributions = 0
    gamma = 0.2

    for count in xrange(len(x)):
        sum_contributions += (x[count] / y[count]) ** gamma
    value = math.pow(sum_contributions, 1 / gamma)
    return -value

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.array([sum(x) - 1])})

y = [0.5, 0.3, 0.2]
initial_x = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]

opt = minimize(objective_function, initial_x, args=(y,), method='SLSQP',  
constraints=cons,bounds=[(0, 1)] * len(x))
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you were more specific about what 'lots of trying' entailed to illuminate the goal of your question.

Comment: Your code works for me. What's the problem your getting? I get optimal `x_opt: array([ 0.29465573,  0.33480638,  0.37053789])`. All I had to change was `bounds` should have `len(initial_x)` or `len(y)` in it, since `x` is not defined in your code.

Comment: @askewchan , Might be a numerical stability issue. On my Mac I am getting `nan``nan``nan`, `'Iteration limit exceeded'`

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, numerical optimizer doesn't work for whatever reason. We can parametrize the problem slightly different and it will just work. (and might work faster)

For example, for bounds of `(0,1)`, we can have a transform function such that values in `(-inf, +inf)`, after being transformed, will end up in `(0,1)`

We can do a similar trick with the equality constraints. For example, we can reduce the dimension from 3 to 2, since the last element in `x` has to be `1-sum(x)`.

If it still won't work, we can switch to a optimizer that dose not require information from derivative, such as `Nelder Mead`.

And also there is [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

```
In [111]:

def trans_x(x):
    x1 = x**2/(1+x**2)
    z  = np.hstack((x1, 1-sum(x1)))
    return z

def F(x, y, gamma = 0.2):
    z = trans_x(x)
    return -(((z/y)**gamma).sum())**(1./gamma)
In [112]:

opt = minimize(F, np.array([0., 1.]), args=(np.array(y),),
               method='Nelder-Mead')
opt
Out[112]:
  status: 0
    nfev: 96
 success: True
     fun: -265.27701747828007
       x: array([ 0.6463264,  0.7094782])
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 52
```

The result is:

```
In [113]:

trans_x(opt.x)
Out[113]:
array([ 0.29465097,  0.33482303,  0.37052601])
```

And we can visualize it, with:

```
In [114]:

x1 = np.linspace(0,1)
y1 = np.linspace(0,1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x1,y1)
Z = np.array([F(item, y) for item 
              in np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel())).T]).reshape((len(x1), -1), order='F')
Z = np.fliplr(Z)
Z = np.flipud(Z)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 50)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @CT Zhu, brilliant solution. What does the `x1 = x**2/(1+x**2)` do?

Comment: for `x` in `(-inf, +inf)`, 'transform' it to `x1` in `(0, 1)`.  Sort of doing the same thing as setting bounds, as the OP requires 'x must be in the interval (0,1)'.

Comment: It actually transforms -inf to 1! It works only for (0, +inf)

Comment: Can we use 'BFGS' instead of 'Nelder-Mead'?

Comment: Is there a reason you used  'Nelder-Mead'? How does the code ensure all values are positive?

Comment: I don't think it has to be `nelder-mead`, other minimizer should work as well.  Solutions are not ensured to be positive either, but applying `trans_x` function will transform the solution to `(0,1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Even tough this questions is a bit dated I wanted to add an alternative solution which might be useful for others stumbling upon this question in the future.

It turns our your problem is solvable analytically. You can start by writing down the Lagrangian of the (equality constrained) optimization problem:

```
L = \sum_i (x_i/y_i)^\gamma - \lambda (\sum x_i - 1)
```

The optimal solution is found by setting the first derivative of this Lagrangian to zero:

```
0 = \partial L / \partial x_i = \gamma x_i^{\gamma-1}/\y_i - \lambda
=> x_i \propto y_i^{\gamma/(\gamma - 1)}
```

Using this insight the optimization problem can be solved simply and efficiently by:

```
In [4]:
def analytical(y, gamma=0.2):
    x = y**(gamma/(gamma-1.0))
    x /= np.sum(x)
    return x
xanalytical = analytical(y)
xanalytical, objective_function(xanalytical, y)
Out [4]:
(array([ 0.29466774,  0.33480719,  0.37052507]), -265.27701765929692)
```

CT Zhu's solution is elegant but it might violate the positivity constraint on the third coordinate. For `gamma = 0.2` this does not seem to be a problem in practice, but for different gammas you easily run into trouble:

```
In [5]:
y = [0.2, 0.1, 0.8]
opt = minimize(F, np.array([0., 1.]), args=(np.array(y), 2.0),
               method='Nelder-Mead')
trans_x(opt.x), opt.fun
Out [5]:
(array([ 1.,  1., -1.]), -11.249999999999998)
```

For other optimization problems with the same probability simplex constraints as your problem, but for which there is no analytical solution, it might be worth looking into projected gradient methods or similar. These methods leverage the fact that there is fast algorithm for the projection of an arbitrary point onto this set see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Projection_onto_the_standard_simplex.

(To see the complete code and a better rendering of the equations take a look at the Jupyter notebook http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/andim/pysnippets/blob/master/optimization-simplex-constraints.ipynb)

Comment: Andi, thanks. But the optimization problem I was trying to solve is somewhat different from the one you solve using analytical means. Here is the complete problem:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168338/explicit-solution-to-optimization-problem

I'd be happy to hear about analytical solutions and fast numerical approximations.  Thanks :-

Comment: If the third parameter must remain positive, would something like this work?


    `# a = third coordinate (positivity constraint)`
    `a = abs(a)`